# Typeahead.js - Populate dataset

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I am using the Twitter typeahead.js header and the following is my code that works. However i would like to know if there was a way I could populate my dataset using a function instead of an array in local. Your help is much appreciated.

```
    <input id="look" placeholder="search" autocomplete="off" />
        <button id="btn">Submit</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#look").typeahead({
                name: 'accounts',
//Would like to use a function to populate my dataset here instead of this array
                local: ['timtrueman', 'JakeHarding', 'vskarich']
            });

            $("#btn").click(function () {
                $("#look").typeahead('setQuery', 't');
                $("#look").focus();
            });

        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of how do you want to populate it? Or do you mean using AJAX with typeahead.js?

Comment: I also want to know how to do this. I want a js module to handle all my AJAX comms and would like to plug this in to typeahead.js

Comment: Hieu, I would like to do something like this: local: function PopulateList(){}. I am calling a c# Web Service to populate the list. I hope that helps.

Comment: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ might help

Answer (score 1):

Since `local` provides only static data, I think `remote` suits your need better:

```
$('#look').typeahead({
    name: 'accounts',
    remote: '/your/backend/url?q=%QUERY'
});
```

So typeahead will send AJAX request to `/your/backend/url` with parameter `q` with value is the value you type. Your backend should be able to return a response for that lookup request.

If you want to debug the response from your backend and process that data, use this:

```
$('#look').typeahead({
    name: 'accounts',
    remote: {
        url: '/your/backend/url?q=%QUERY',
        filter: function(resp) {
            var dataset = [];
            console.log(resp); // debug the response here

            // do some filtering if needed with the response          

            return dataset;
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will be available in the upcoming release (v0.10.0).

See the **source** parameter under [Sections](https://github.com/jharding/typeahead.js/blob/v0.10.0-README/README.md#sections) in the version's readme on GitHub.

Extract from the readme:

> A typeahead is composed of one or more sections. For simple use cases,
>   one section will usually suffice. If however you wanted to build
>   something like the search typeahead on twitter.com, you'd need
>   multiple sections.
>        Sections can be configured using the following options.
>
> - *name* – The name of the section. Defaults to a random number.
> - ***source*** – The backing data source for the section. Can be either a dataset or a function with the signature (query, cb). If the
>     latter, cb is expected to be invoked with an array of datums that are
>     a match for query. Required.
> - *highlight* – If true, when suggestions are rendered, pattern matches for the current query in text nodes will be wrapped in a
>     strong element. Defaults to false.
> - *templates* – A hash of templates to be used when rendering the section.
>
>   - *empty* – Rendered when 0 suggestions are available for the given       query. Can be either a HTML string or a precompiled template. If it's 
>       a precompiled template, the passed in context will contain query.
>   - *header* – Rendered at the top of the section. Can be either a HTML string or a precompiled template. If it's a precompiled template,
>       the passed in context will contain query and isEmpty.
>   - *footer* – Rendered at the bottom of the section. Can be either a HTML string or a precompiled template. If it's a precompiled template,
>       the passed in context will contain query and isEmpty.
>   - suggestion – Used to render a single suggestion. If set, this has to be a precompiled tempate. The associated datum object will serves
>       as the context. Defaults to the value of the datum wrapped in a p tag.